# Crear un modelo con un ForeignKey y otro campo

Tags: django, django-models

Les deseo un buen inicio de semana y aprovecho para plantear una pregunta sobre la implementación de mi modelo en django 1.9 usando mysql:

Tengo un catálogo de autores y cada uno tiene un id único, cada autor participa en uno o en varios trabajos, y adicionalmente, existe un campo de orden de mención dentro del trabajo.

Inicialmente pensé que el campo "orden" (de orden de aparición en el trabajo) debería de estar en la tabla Autores, algo así:

```
class Autor(models.Model):
orden = models.CharField(max_length=2)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
primer_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=40)
segundo_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
correo = models.EmailField(blank=True)
institucion = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["primer_apellido"]
    verbose_name_plural ="Autores"

def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' %(self.nombre, self.primer_apellido, self.segundo_apellido)
```

pero luego me di cuenta de que el que ponga en la tabla autores, el orden en el que aparece en un trabajo, no me va a permitir que utilice el registro del mismo autor en otro trabajo, ya que puede ser que tenga otro orden dentro del segundo trabajo -orden, se refiere más bien a la posición en que se menciona su nombre dentro del trabajo, el autor principal es el 1, el segundo autor tiene el orden 2, etc.-

Se que necesito una tabla intermedia para que se relacionen los autores, los trabajos y el orden del mismo, por lo que mi modelo sería algo así:

```
class Contribucion(models.Model):
autores = models.ForeignKey(Autor)
orden_autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor.orden)
trabajo = models.ForeignKey(Trabajo)
```

Pero al momento de realizar un `check` desde manage.py, me devuelve el error: `AttributeError: type object 'Autor' has no attribute 'orden'`

La pregunta es: cómo podría incluir en el modelo el campo orden para que cuando recupere los registros de la tabla, el orden de mención de los autores lo haga estableciendo un ordenamiento ascendente con ese campo.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su apoyo.

Gustavo.

Comment: Cómo has definido la relación M2M en el modelo Trabajo?

Comment: Me faltó esa parte jejeje, pero así la he manejado:
`class Trabajo(models.Model):

registro = models.CharField(max_length=4)
titulo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
area_tematica = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Areas_Tematicas_Choices)
participantes = models.ManyToManyField(Autor, through = 'Contribucion')

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo`

Comment: Creo que el problema es que has quitado el campo orden de tu modelo Autor y no has hecho las migraciones necesarias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El campo `orden_autor` no tiene que ser una clave foránea. Basta con que sea un simple campo numérico o una letra que permita su ordenación.

¿Por qué? Cada registro en la tabla `Contribucion` está formado por una combinación única de el autor y el orden.

> Aunque con un poco de orden en el registro de trabajos, el propio campo `id` de la tabla `Contribución` haría la magia. En fin.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
from django.db import models

class Autor(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Trabajo(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Contribucion(models.Model):
  trabajo = models.ForeignKey(Trabajo)
  autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor)
  orden = models.IntegerField()

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ("trabajo", "orden")
```

Como puedes ver, `orden` es solo un campo numérico, pero el modelo tiene un índice compuesto entre `trabajo` y `orden`, de modo que un trabajo no tenga dos número 1, por ejemplo.

Al verificar el modelo, podemos ver lo siguiente.

```
>>> from arte.models import Trabajo, Autor, Contribucion
>>> t = Trabajo(nombre="algo")
>>> a1 = Autor(nombre="Fulano")
>>> a2 = Autor(nombre="Sutano")
>>> c1 = Contribucion(trabajo=t, autor=a1, orden=1)
>>> c2 = Contribucion(trabajo=t, autor=a2, orden=1)
>>> t.save()
>>> a1.save()
>>> a2.save()
>>> c1.save()
```

Pero al guardar `c2` que repite el mismo número de orden y el mismo trabajo, obtenemos un error:

```
>>> c2.save()
…
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: arte_contribucion.trabajo_id, arte_contribucion.orden
```

Si cambiamos el valor de `orden` en `c2` y volvemos a guardar, ya no tenemos problemas…

```
>>> c2 = Contribucion(trabajo=t, autor=a2, orden=2)
>>> c2.save()
>>> c2
<Contribucion: Contribucion object>
>>> c2.id
2
```

Mi opinión es que el campo `orden` no debe ser una clave foránea, sino un simple campo numérico, lo que hace más simple todos tus modelos.

La referencia, con la versión 1.9 de Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Muchas gracias @toledano por el apoyo, efectivamente el campo de orden, debe de quedar en esa tabla intermedia que relaciona tanto trabajos como autores!!